# new module installation but how to bin/magento setup:upgrade on remote server

Tags: magento2, module

I have installed a new module and added `modulevendor_modulename=>1` in the  config.php file, but this gave me an error of:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:263:"Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:...
```

I don't have ssh access, is there any to register/run this new module in my remote server?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to my answer in the below post

[Magento 2: programmatically run setup upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131804/magento-2-programmatically-run-setup-upgrade/132168)

```
<?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    include('../app/bootstrap.php');
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


    $modules = array('VENDORNAME_MODULENAME');
    try{
        /* Code to enable a module [ php bin/magento module:enable VENDORNAME_MODULENAME ] */
        $moduleStatus = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Module\Status')->setIsEnabled(true,$modules);


        /* Code to run setup upgrade [ php bin/magento setup:upgrade ] */
        $installerFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Setup\Test\Unit\Console\Command\UpgradeCommandTest')->testExecute();


        /* Code to clean cache [ php bin/magento:cache:clean ] */
        try{
            $_cacheTypeList = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
            $_cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool');
            $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                $_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
            }
            foreach ($_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
                $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $msg = 'Error during cache clean: '.$e->getMessage();die();
        }   
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $msg = 'Error during module enabling : '.$e->getMessage();die();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use System Upgrade tools. See 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html for more details